# Fixing broken path for renamed feature class in multiple .mxd's?

Tags: arcpy, mxd, data-source

I have read up on the [ESRI technical article here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm).

Basically I had a corrupt feature class that I rebuilt from a backup and renamed.  As I created more .mxd's with this renamed feature class, all .mxd's previous to the corruption now have broken sources.  I found a code snippet on the article for replacing a data source.  The problem is, I want to run this code on many .mxd's in a folder but this code only runs on single .mxd's. I have little python experience so I need some help here.

Side Note:  I am delivering these .mxd files along with the FGDB to a client.  I am batch running a script to enable relative links on all .mxd files.  Will this affect the code I need to run on fixing data sources?

In this code, MajorRoads is being renamed to Highways.

```py
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        if lyr.dataSource == r"C:\Project\Data\Transportation.gdb\MajorRoads":
            lyr.replaceDataSource(r"C:\Project\Data\Transportation.gdb", "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "Highways")
            lyr.name = "Highways"
            mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project2.mxd")
del mxd
```

Comment: I corrected the indenting of your code block to not contain errors, keep that in mind in relation to the answer I have given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to apply this code to many mxds not just one. To do this you can use the python module `glob` it is in the standard Python library. You would match all .mxds within a folder like this

```py
import glob, os
in_folder = r'C:\the_folder\containing_mxds'
mxd_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(in_folder, '*.mxd'))
```

Calling `glob.glob` in the snippet above will return a list of file paths that have an extension of .mxd. The `*` is a wildcard and matches all characters. From there you use your same code, with minor adjustments, but inside a loop that loops over the mxd paths in the list of mxds, `mxd_paths`. Like this:

```py
for mxd_path in mxd_paths:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
    #perform the rest of your code here
    bfixed_layer = False
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd):
        if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
            if lyr.dataSource == r"C:\Project\Data\Transportation.gdb\MajorRoads":
                lyr.replaceDataSource(r"C:\Project\Data\Transportation.gdb", "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "Highways")
                lyr.name = "Highways"
                bfixed_layer = True
    #only save a copy of the mxd if you fixed the layer
    if bfixed_layer == True:
         #to save a copy with a different name, isolate the filename without extension
         mxd_base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(mxd_path))[0]
         new_mxd_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mxd_path), mxd_base_name + '_2.mxd')
         mxd.saveACopy(new_mxd_path)
```

In the snippet above I basically used your method to create the new path name. However just appending a '_2' to the name, is not a very safe way to rename a file. If you wanted to be sure that the name was unique you can use `os.path.exists` before saving the new mxd. If the new file path exists, rather than appending '_2' to the existing file name, the `time` module can be used to create a unique time stamp which can be appended to your new file name. Something like this:

```py
if os.path.exists(new_mxd_path):
    unique_time_stamp = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
    new_mxd_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mxd_path), mxd_base_name + unique_time_stamp + '.mxd')
    mxd.saveACopy(new_mxd_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I feel I am almost there but the script is only outputting one "mxd_2" as opposed to the whole folder.  Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @gnarkilleptic yes if your loops are not properly embedded that would occur. See the updated code in my answer. If you found this helpful, upvotes are appreciated :-)